# Error 500 on collectives members tab when duration is 12 months

Tags: bug, status-completed, collectives

As the title says, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud?tab=members&TimeSpanFilter=Year&Page=1) page is returning 500 errors and it's been a while. It's not a crucial thing like Q&A part but I just thought I should confirm if that's only me.

[image]

Updated view:

[image]

Comment: SQL Server timeout because of the number of members?

Comment: @CodeCaster interesting but the stats shows there are less than 800 members (not sure how accurate/realtime) they are.

Comment: it can't be due to 800 member entries, it might be out of bounds on the time duration - confirmed to be an issue on my end too.

Comment: No repro - might be fixed?

Comment: @Zoe I just checked it and the page seems to be working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out. This issue was temporary and solved.